# Does cf push respect the use of .gitignore?

Tags: git, push, ibm-cloud

I'm using the `.gitignore` file below with the hope that when I push my application, the tmp directory and swap files will be ignored. That isn't happening though and now I am wondering if `cf push` even considers `.gitignore`?

```
*.swp
tmp/
```

Does anyone know if `cf push` takes a `.gitignore` file into consideration?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The file `.cfignore` is used for that purpose -- it is not the same as `.gitignore`, but rather its analogy for the `cf` tool.

The reason for not using them for the same purpose is that you may have for example files that are used for your build (or even source code!) that go to Git but not to the Bluemix runtime, and alternatively, other files like credentials or configurations which are to be deployed with the app but still not go to Git. (You would use `.cfignore` to exclude the first set, and `.gitignore` in the other case.)

Answer (score 4):

I discovered that `cf push` does NOT use `.gitignore` rather it uses its own file called `.cfignore` that has to be placed at the root directory of the application you are pushing.

The rules for `.cfignore` and `.gitignore` appear to tbe the same. (one pattern per line) However since the `.cfignore` file must be at the root of the applicaiton the patterns in the file must take that into consideration.

Using the file above I am now able to push my application without all the `.swp` files or anything in my `<application-root>/tmp` directory.